# D3.js bar chart - axis and labels not working / transitioning

Tags: javascript, d3.js

first time using D3.js. I am stuck at getting my bar chart to display value labels on the bars and transitioning the x/y axis when data is refreshed. I get no errors and the code came from putting a couple of examples together. Code is below, [jfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/TheRealPapa/h8Rsg/32/) for working example. In the real code I am pulling data using d3.json, in the jsfiddle I am using static vars, fyi. Any help is appreciated.

Code below:

```
var data;

var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 30
},
width = 838 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0.05);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(10);

var svg = d3.select("#daychart")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


d3.json("http://10.0.0.13/sma/sma-php/inverterdata.php?var=CDAY&id=C1200031", function (error, data) {
data.forEach(function (d) {
    d.max_energy = +d.max_energy;
});

x.domain(data.map(function (d) {
    return d.xaxis;
}));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
    return d.max_energy;
})]);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(0)")
    .attr("y", 23)
    .attr("x", 340)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "bottom")
    .text("Timeline");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(0)")
    .attr("y", -15)
    .attr("x", -25)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "top")
    .text("Energy - KWh");

svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function (d) {
    return x(d.xaxis);
})
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
    .attr("y", function (d) {
    return y(d.max_energy);
})
    .transition().delay(function (d, i) {
    return i * 10;
}).duration(10)
    .attr("height", function (d) {
    return height - y(d.max_energy);
});

//Create labels
svg.selectAll("text")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .text(function (d) {
    return parseFloat(Math.round(d.max_energy * 100) / 100).toFixed(1);
})
    .attr("x", function (d) {
    return x(d.xaxis) + x.rangeBand() / 2;
})
    .attr("y", function (d) {
    return height - y(d.max_energy) + 14;
})
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
    .attr("font-size", "11px")
    .attr("fill", "black");

//});

//On click, update with new data            
d3.select("p").on("click", function () {

    // Get the data again
        d3.json("http://10.0.0.13/sma/sma-php/inverterdata.php?var=PDAY&id=P100023", function (error, data) {
    data.forEach(function (d) {
        d.max_energy = +d.max_energy;
    });

    // Scale the range of the data again 
    x.domain(data.map(function (d) {
        return d.xaxis;
    }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
        return d.max_energy;
    })]);

    // Make the changes
    svg.selectAll(".bar") // change the bar
    .data(data) // Update the data within.
    .transition().delay(function (d, i) {
        return i / data.length * 1000;
    })
        .duration(500)
        .attr("x", function (d) {
        return x(d.xaxis);
    })
        .attr("y", function (d) {
        return y(d.max_energy);
    })
        .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
        .attr("height", function (d) {
        return height - y(d.max_energy);
    });

    //Update all labels
    svg.selectAll("text")
        .data(data).transition()
        .delay(function (d, i) {
        return i / data.length * 1000;
    })
        .duration(500)
        .text(function (d) {
        return parseFloat(Math.round(d.max_energy * 100) / 100).toFixed(1);
    })
        .attr("x", function (d, i) {
        return x(i) + x.rangeBand() / 2;
    })
        .attr("y", function (d) {
        return height - y(d.max_energy) + 24;
    });

    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<p>CLICK ME</p>
<svg id="daychart"></svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually easier than you think. You just need to call the axis functions again:

```
svg.select("g.x").call(xAxis);
svg.select("g.y").call(yAxis);
```

Changed jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/h8Rsg/35/).

To get the labels to work, you can give those `text` elements a specific class and select accordingly. By default, D3 matches elements based on the index. That is, after you've added the axis labels by calling the axes, those will be selected and matched against the data. Therefore, the `.enter()` selection will be empty with no new labels added.

Jsfiddle with that as well [here](http://jsfiddle.net/h8Rsg/41/).

Comment: Hi Lars, THANKS!!! your JFiddle link is not working though. Also, why are my bar chart labels not appearing? Thanks!

Comment: Whoops, sorry. Not sure what went wrong there -- link fixed. Not sure what kind of labels you want -- something like in [this tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/)?

Comment: Hi Lars, thanks again! Yes, this is the tutorial I pulled the code from, but unfortunately the value labels on the bars do not work. I want to place the value at the top of every bar. Many thanks again for taking the time!

Comment: Ah, well, should have just let @LarsKotthoff finish off the explanation...  His is so much more concise than mine!

Comment: The original fiddle seems to have been deleted. The relevant parts of the code are in the answer though.

Answer (score 2):

For the second part of your question:

The labels weren't showing up properly because you were just using `selectAll("text")` to grab them.  The problem with that is that the tick labels on the axes are text elements, too, so they were getting selected and assigned the data -- but then not included in your "enter". That is also why the axis labels moved off screen when you updated the data (since in that case, you were setting attributes on all elements, not just new ones).

**To fix:**  Add a class to the bar labels, and use it to select them specifically:

```
svg.selectAll("text.barLabels") //use this selector in your update as well
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .classed("barLabels", true) //remember to actually add the class!
```

It should all work now ...almost.

You could probably figure out this on your own, but your label y-positioning function wasn't taking into consideration the fact that you were using an inverted scale, so the labels all ended up in weird positions.  You also need to change

```
.attr("y", function (d) {
    return height - y(d.max_energy) + 24;
});
```

to

```
.attr("y", function (d) { 
    return y(d.max_energy) + 24;
})
```

or

```
.attr("y", function (d) { 
    return Math.min(y(d.max_energy) + 24, height);
})
```

so that "0.0" labels aren't positioned beyond the axis line; or even

```
.attr("y", function (d,i) { 
    return Math.min(y(d.max_energy) + 24*(1+i%2), height);
})
```

so that adjacent labels don't overlap if they are too wide for the bar. (The `i%2` just returns 0 for even numbers and 1 for odd numbers; the modulo operator `%` gives back the "remainder" from integer division.)

The last version is what I've got implemented here: http://jsfiddle.net/h8Rsg/40/